# Vendor whitepaper says: 5Mpps no prob. I'm already hitting a wall at 120kpps. Where's the bottleneck?

Tags: networking, performance, windows-server-2012-r2, udp

HP's [whitepaper on their QLogic (fka Broadcom) NetXtreme II adapters](http://h20195.www2.hp.com/V2/getpdf.aspx/4AA4-0025ENW.pdf), which includes the specific NIC that I'm testing, states (page 7) that their small packet performance for packets up to 256 bytes/packet is above 5,000,000 packets/sec.

In my tests with an app where I disabled all processing except the mere UDP receive part, I can go up to 120,000 packets/sec only. The packets are evenly distributed over 12 multicast groups.

I noticed that there is **one core** (out of 12 cores each on the 2 sockets) whose load gradually increases when I crank up the UDP send rate and **maxes out at around 120,000**. But I don't know what that core is doing and why. It is not a single-thread bottleneck in my app, because it does not matter if I run a single instance of the app for all multicast groups, or 12 instances which handle 1 multicast group each. So the bottleneck is not my receiver app.

MSI is enabled (verified via the ["resources by type" view in the device manager](http://forums.guru3d.com/showthread.php?t=378044)) and RSS too is enabled in the NIC settings, with 8 queues. So what is clinging to that one core? All NIC offloading features are currently on, but turning them off did not help.

So where could the bottleneck be?

System details:

- ProLiant BL460c Gen9
- Intel Xeon E5-2670 v3 (2 x 12cores)
- HP FlexFabric 10Gb 2-port 536FLB NIC
- Windows 2012 R2

Comment: Probably all rx and tx interrupts are handled by the same core. I don't know much about windows but there should be some SMP affinity to set up in order to spread evenly relevant IRQs.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> RSS too is enabled in the NIC settings, with 8 queues.

Which unfortunately did not mean that RSS was being employed, as

```
netsh int tcp show global
```

showed:

```
TCP Global Parameters
----------------------------------------------
Receive-Side Scaling State : disabled
```

After running (btw without rebooting)

```
netsh int tcp set global rss=enabled
```

RSS started working and the load that formerly heaped on that one poor core now gets evenly distributed over many cores on one of the 2 NUMA nodes.

I haven't verified if that would allow me to handle the Mpps loads advertised, but the ceiling was lifted sufficiently to benchmark what I needed to.