# Is it possible to process millions of datagrams per second with Windows, using a vendor agnostic API?

Tags: networking, performance, linux-networking, windows-server-2012-r2

I am investigating if I can implement an HPC app in Windows that **receives small UDP multicast datagrams (mostly 100-400 Bytes) at a high rate, using a dozen or up to maybe 200 multicast groups** (i.e. using MSI-X and RSS I can scale to multiple cores), does some processing per packet, and then sends it out. Sending via TCP I managed to go up as far as I needed to (6.4Gb/sec) without hitting a wall, but receiving datagrams at high pps rates turned out to be an issue.

In a [recent test](https://serverfault.com/q/693295/124382) on a high-spec NUMA machine with a 2-port 10Gb ethernet NIC on Windows 2012 R2, I was only able to **receive hundreds of thousands of UDP datagrams per second** (early drop, i.e. without actually processing the data, to remove the processing overhead of my app from the equation to see how fast it gets) using 2x12 cores, and the kernel part of the 12 multicast groups tested seemed to get distributed across 8 or 10 cores of one NUMA node (*Max RSS queues* was set to 16)  - albeit with a .net app, so native apps should be able to go faster.

But even [Len Holgate](http://www.lenholgate.com/) **only managed to receive UDP packets at 500kpps** in [his high-performance Windows RIO tests](http://www.serverframework.com/asynchronousevents/2012/08/winsock-registered-io-io-completion-port-performance.html), using a UDP payload of 1024 bytes.

In [QLogic's whitepaper](http://h20195.www2.hp.com/V2/getpdf.aspx/4AA4-0025ENW.pdf) (OS under test not mentioned) the limits for "multi-threaded super-small packet routing" (so that includes both receiving and subsequent sending?) are set at **5.7Mpps**. In [articles](http://people.netfilter.org/hawk/presentations/LCA2015/net_stack_challenges_100G_LCA2015.pdf) on [Linux networking](https://lwn.net/Articles/629155/), the limits are set at **1Mpps to 2Mpps** per core (reportedly scaling up more or less linearly), or even **15Mpps** with special solutions that bypass the kernel.

E.g. [**netmap**](http://info.iet.unipi.it/~luigi/netmap/)

> can generate traffic at line rate (**14.88Mpps**) on a 10GigE link with just a single core running at 900Mhz. This equals to about 60-65 clock cycles per packet, and scales well with cores and clock frequency (with 4 cores, line rate is achieved at less than 450 MHz). **Similar rates are reached on the receive side**.

So how far can I take Windows 2012 R2, with good, standard Ethernet NICs, doing standard Ethernet (rather than e.g. *Converged Ethernet*), using vendor-agnostic APIs?

Comment: Other what? Please edit your post.

Comment: You need to clarify what you're asking.  Max throughput varies wildly depending on a lot of variables; what are the circumstances and required speeds given the load? Is it failing to meet that need, if so why? Is this purely an academic question, If so this may not be the best place for it.

Comment: @DavidV Fair enough, I added a preamble that shows that I'm actually trying to get something done.

Comment: This has turned from infrastructure to development.

Answer (score 2):

Its possible to bypass the kernel and use netdirect with hpc installed. see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc904344(v=vs.85).aspx I cannot locate any perf data (I suspect it would vary per vendor since it uses NIC hardware more directly than the other APIs) but it should be on par with other kernel bypass solutions in Linux (kernel bypass is kernel bypass)
EDIT:
So if you are going to refuse to actually use the hardware provided don't expect the performance you can get from a standard NIC using the drivers required. No converged Ethernet is required (I'm not sure how that came up), but that's how venders expose the hardware features to the OS- drivers, I'm not sure why you even refer to the qlogic paper (which is specifically referring to using their nic hardware- something you are saying you don't want to do) same with the netmap paper (uses modified drivers).

Comment: Thanks Jim. Unfortunately, the vendor/hardware specific nature is something I want to avoid (but had not spelled out until I just now added it to the title), like is the case with many of the high-performance solutions in Linux, including netmap.

Comment: Re: your *EDIT*:  1. Using vendor/hardware agnostic APIs is not the same as "refusing to actually use the hardware". 2. "Converged Ethernet" was not addressed at you - it is in my question, not in a comment to you - and merely excludes one possible way to get more performance, but my requirements do not allow for it. 3. The HP paper on the QLogic adapter is one example I give to support my "Mpps are apparently possible" assumption, netmap being another. 4. Netmap does need driver support, as do many other techniques such as RSS. These features can still be used in a vendor-agnostic way.

Comment: Re:" refusing to use the hardware". It is in fact refusing to use the hardware when you specify thing like "standard NIC".  The QLogic paper specifically shows that the only way to achieve that level of performance is by addressing the hardware, hardware that varies between vendors. In short you are asking for 2 mutually exclusive things,  high performance from unspecific drivers, and a desire to not use the high speed APIs in conjunction with the required drivers.

Comment: I'd be happy to try Network Direct, if it could be used to send/receive IPv4, UDP, and TCP packets via standard Ethernet, using an API that is tied to a particular NIC. But documentation is sparse, and so far I have only come across support for concepts like RDMA and MPI, which are not generic IP/UDP/TCP on top of Ethernet. If you have any information to the contrary, that would be great.